# 'display: table;' on container and 'display:table-cell;' on children?

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-tables

Is it okay to have `display: table;` on the container element, and `display: table-cell;` on its children, or should there be a wrapper with `display: table-row;` in-between?

**I mean...**

```
<div style="display: table;">
   <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
   <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
</div>
```

**or**

```
<div style="display: table;">
   <div style="display: table-row;">
      <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
      <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

`display: table-row;` makes sense when you have multiple rows. But in my case, I am only using it for a multi-column responsive layout (which implies single row, obviously) as it's less complex than using `float` or something else.

So, the question is, for a single-row multi-column layout, is it okay to have `display: table;` on the container element, and `display: table-cell;` on its children, without a `display: table-row;` wrapper in between?

I've seen some sites do this (i.e. they don't use `display: table-row;`). [Here's an example](http://mashable.com/).

Comment: It is valid. Anonymous `table-row`s will get inserted automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single [anonymous table row box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#anonymous-boxes) will be generated within your outer `div` (the table) to contain all the inner `div`s (the table cells), so it's perfectly acceptable if you know you want all the table cells to belong in the same row.

Comment: Is it better to style the outer div `table-row` or `table` (assuming the absence of any outer `table`-styled elements)?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: That I'm not sure, as table layout is one of those topics I'm unfamiliar with :) I do know that either option you choose should always generate the appropriate anonymous box. If the outer element is a table then the above happens; if it's a table row then an anonymous table box is generated around it instead.

Comment: Thinking of it, can `table-row`s have margins and padding? I think they can't, but `table`s can.

Comment: Then `table`s have a certain edge over `table-row`s (literally `:-)`)